# issue with apostrophes in pagination

Tags: javascript, php, pagination

I'm having an issue with my pagination when a query have some apostrophes in it.
This is what i'm using to creat the pagination :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination({
         totalPages: 50,
         visiblePages: 5,
         prev: '<',
         next: '>',
         first: '<<',
         last: '>>',
         href: 'http://www.monsite.com/search/index.php?a=web&q={$query}&page={{number}}',
         onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                 $('#page-content').text('Page ' + page);
         }
     });
</script>
```

For instance, for a search with the word "d'entreprise" the pagination disappear of my page.

And if i write it like that "d entreprise", the pagination is ok and i have this link :

```
http://www.monsite.com/search/index.php?a=web&q=d%20entreprise&page=2
```

Someone have an idea ?
Am i obligated to do a "replace" or something like that, to change my apostrophe ?
Or there is a way to keep it in my query and pagination ?

Comment: And where is `{$query}` and `{{number}}` coming from? You probably want to urlencode those ?

Comment: Use `urlencode()` to encode special characters in URLs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply :)
I'm really a noob, i'm sorry. 
I must say that i don't know where `{{number}}` is coming from, i don't have it on my php pages. But that still works...
The `{$query}` is from my php page i think, and it's like this :  `$query = rawurldecode($_GET['q']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're causing a JS syntax error, by directly dumping text from PHP into a javascript context. E.g. this code:

```
$foo = "D'Enterprise";

echo "<script> var foo = '$foo';</script>";
```

would send this to the user:

```
 var foo = 'D'Enterprise';
           ^-^----start/stop string
              ^^^^^^^^^^--- "Enteprise" - undefined variable
                        ^^--- start an unterminated string
```

If you'd one ANY kind of basic debugging, like checking your browser's console, you'd have seen the error.

In short, **NEVER** directly output text from PHP into a "foreign" context, especially if that context is some other language. You can EASILY cause syntax errors in that language (exactly as your are doing right now). Always use appropriate output methods, which for PHP  generating Javascript, is to use JSON:

```
$foo = "D'Enterprise";
$temp = json_encode($foo);

echo "<script> var foo = $temp; </script>";
```

which produces

```
var foo = 'D\'Enterprise';
```

and is perfectly valid JS code.

Comment: Hello Marc B, 
thanks for your answer. :)
I saw the issue in the console, but that's just write SyntaxError, that's why i looked here and elsewhere.
Ok so i need to json encode my query before using it in my javascript, am i right ?

Comment: yes. whatever you output from PHP **HAS** to be valid for the context it's outputting it into. Since that context is a javascript, your php output has to be valid JS string contents.